# Spring MVC Request Mapping, dealing with inherited urls

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring MVC. As part of my practice I am using below resource mappings.

#### Case1

`@RequestMapping("/training")
    public String training(){
        return "training";
    }`

#### Case2

`@RequestMapping("/services/training")
    public String training(){
        return "training";
    }`

This is the content of my jsp page. `<img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="./resources/images/toplogo.png">`. In case 1 it is working fine, but it is expected to be `<img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="../resources/images/toplogo.png">` in case 2`(One extra . in url)`. I know that this is for accessing the file, but as i want to use this in my template for spring-tiles integration, my expectation is for both type of urls it has to work. Can someone please help me how to achieve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:
[spring:url](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html)

```
<spring:url var="url" value="/resources/images/toplogo.png">
<img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="${url}"/>
```

This should work.